# How to set an ints Hex Literal from a string,

Tags: c#, .net, xml, hex

Im attempting to load a hex literal from an xml settings file, I can parse the xml just fine and get the required string from the file,

but i cant seem to get it to set an int variables value :/

Code:

```
    int PlayerBaseAddress = System.Convert.ToInt32(ConfigLoader.GetSetting("PlayerBaseAddress"));
    // Input string was not in a correct format.

    public static string GetSetting(string Val)
    {
       // This loads from the xml file, Pretend its hardcoded to return a string of 0x17EAAF00
    }

    int PlayerBaseAddress = 0x17EAAF00; // This works.
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have to supply the base of the string to the overloaded method [`Convert.ToInt32(String value, Int32 fromBase)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1k20k614.aspx).

```
Int32 value = Convert.ToInt32(hexString, 16);
```