# Read address using Console.ReadLine() C#

Tags: c#, int, hex

I tried to read a memory address using:

```
int address = Console.ReadLine();
```

As you see this doesn't work, how can I do something like this?

Value to read: 0x007FCB20

Comment: I'm trying to receive it from the user.

Comment: As the name implies you can read a *line* of text. Then you can treat this *string* according to some rule and covert it in context. You are probably interested in turning the *string* "0x007FCB20" into the integer that it represents, in hex. In this case, look up "convert hex string to number", eg. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4275440/how-to-convert-hex-string-to-hex-number?rq=1 , http://stackoverflow.com/questions/848869/how-to-set-an-ints-hex-literal-from-a-string?lq=1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Capture it as a string first. e.g.

```
string address = Console.ReadLine();
```

Then convert the string to an integer:

```
Int32 addressInt = Convert.ToInt32(address, 16);
```

Comment: But it needs to be integer.

Answer (score 0):

He answered my question: https://stackoverflow.com/users/2864740/user2864740

The solution: [How to set an ints Hex Literal from a string,](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/848869/how-to-set-an-ints-hex-literal-from-a-string?lq=1)